# Connect Nitrous.io to Bitbucket Git SSH Public Key

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, public-key, nitrousio

I can't connect my Bitbucket git repos to Nitrous.io. Here is the error I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

At first I thought you had to have your computer's public key in Nitrous and Bitbucket to connect them, but that doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you have to do is:

Go to your nitrous box (IDE or Terminal), and run this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

which will display the *Nitrous* SSH public key (not your computer's public key, but the one for that box).

Go to Bitbucket > My Account > SSH Keys and paste the Nitrous key in. Be sure to name it Nitrous or something like that so you know what key it is later. Then your repos will connect just fine.